# Sample a Percentage of Entries in a dataframe but with a Lower Limit

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have grouped a dataframe with respect to a property (Gene.Prop). I would like to sample a fraction of the entries in each group (10%). However, I would like to sample at least 5 entries, even if 5 is more than 10% of the number of entries in the group.

```
my_dataframe_1_percent<- domain_annotated_DDR_list_DE%>%
  filter(domain_or_af == "FALSE")%>%
  distinct(sgRNA.sequence, .keep_all = TRUE)%>%
  group_by(Gene.Prop)%>%
  sample_frac(0.01)%>% #How can I add the minimum limit?
  tally()%>%
  ungroup()
```

Expected result:

[image]

(Where n is the number of samples for each property. Note that n>=5 each time.)

Comment: I provided an answer below. One thing to note here is that `sample_frac()`  is superseded and you should now use `slice_sample()`. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/sample_n.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to check the number of rows in each group. If the row number exceeds the threshold, sample proportionally. Otherwise, sample the minimum number of rows.

Here's an example of how to implement this.

## Example Data and Sampling Parameters

```r
# Packages
library(dplyr)

# Example data: 10 rows in group a, 100 in group b
n_a <- 10
n_b <- 100
total <- n_a + n_b

df <- data.frame(x = 1:total,
                 y = rnorm(total),
                 group = c(rep("a", n_a), rep("b", n_b)))

# Proportion and minimum number of rows to sample
sample_prop <- 0.5
sample_min <- 8
```

## Solution

```r
# Group the data and split each group into a list of tibbles (could use base
# R split alternatively)
df_list <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  group_split()

# Write a function that checks if the number of rows that would be sampled is
# below the minimum. If so, sample the minimum number of rows, otherwise sample
# the proportion.
conditional_sample <- function(dat,
                               sample_min,
                               sample_prop) {
  if (nrow(dat) * sample_prop < sample_min) {
    slice_sample(dat, n = sample_min)
  } else{
    slice_sample(dat, prop = sample_prop)
  }
}

# Apply the function to our list
sampled <- df_list %>%
  lapply(., function(x) {
    conditional_sample(x, sample_min, sample_prop)
  })

# View output
sampled

# Can place back into a single data.frame:
bind_rows(sampled)
```

You could also use `base::split()` if you don't want to use `dplyr` verbs like `group_by()` and it will be a little faster. Could also swap out the `lapply()` for `purrr::map()`.

Comment: See also here for another approach that doesn't split up the data into a list then operator on it. I think the above may be more legible in most cases (and perhaps faster? unclear) but you can also check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74178808/sampling-rows-from-a-grouped-data-frame-conditional-on-group-level-summary-stati