# Sampling rows from a grouped data.frame conditional on group-level summary statistics with dplyr

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data-wrangling

In [this post on sampling a proportion with a lower bound of the number of rows sampled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74176819/sample-a-percentage-of-entries-in-a-dataframe-but-with-a-lower-limit/74178225#74178225) I wrote a function (see below) that takes a data.frame containing some group identifier(s), splits the data.frame by group into a list, and then samples the greater of a proportion and a minimum number of rows.

While this works, I was wondering if there is an efficient way to do this with `summarise` or otherwise not splitting the output of `group_by()` into a list and then iterating across the elements of the list with `map`/`lapply`-like functions. The idea would be to pass the data to `group_by()` and then to `summarise()`, where I would count the number of rows in each group and then sample the proportion or minimal number accordingly using an `if_else` approach. However I was finding that produced various scoping issues or type conflicts. For example, `cur_group` or `cur_data` seem useful to count and subset in the same summarise call, but I'm not sure how to use them properly.

Anyone have any idea for how to do this within `summarise()` or otherwise avoid `split()`ing the data outside of `summarise()`?

```r
library(dplyr)

# Example data: 10 rows in group a, 100 in group b
df <- data.frame(x = 1:110,
                 y = rnorm(110),
                 group = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 100)))

# Proportion and minimum number of rows to sample
sample_prop <- 0.5
sample_min <- 8

# Group the data and split each group into a list of tibbles
df_list <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% group_split()

# Checks if the number of rows that would be sampled is below the minimum. If so, 
# sample the minimum number of rows, otherwise sample the proportion. This is 
# what I'm trying to do within a summarise call.
conditional_sample <- function(dat, sample_min, sample_prop) {
  if (nrow(dat) * sample_prop < sample_min) {
    slice_sample(dat, n = sample_min)
  } else{
    slice_sample(dat, prop = sample_prop)
  }
}

# Apply the function to our list -- ideally this would be unecessary
# within summarise
sampled <- df_list %>%
  lapply(., function(x) {
    conditional_sample(x, sample_min, sample_prop)
  })

bind_rows(sampled) # check out data
```

Comment: Input data could use improvement since it doesn't cover both cases.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento yes sampling without replacement.  I also didn't even think of building up a vector of T/F values for each group, awesome idea. Could similarly get the row indices instead of T/F then use `slice()` i'm thinking.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I think this is the answer to the linked post.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento please post as an answer  so i can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use the `max()` of `sample_min` and `sample_prop * n()` as the sample size:

With `slice()`:

```
library(dplyr)

sample_prop <- 0.5
sample_min <- 8


df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  slice(sample(n(), max(sample_min, floor(sample_prop * n())))) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 58 × 3
       x      y group
   <int>  <dbl> <chr>
 1     1  1.01  a    
 2     3 -0.389 a    
 3     4  0.559 a    
 4     5 -0.594 a    
 5     7 -0.415 a    
 6     8 -1.63  a    
 7     9 -2.27  a    
 8    10 -0.422 a    
 9    11  0.673 b    
10    12 -1.23  b    
# … with 48 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Or equivalently with `filter()`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% sample(n(), max(sample_min, floor(sample_prop * n())))) %>%
  ungroup()
```